# Service stops receiving requests after a failure in ExceptionHandler due to ClientAbortException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have the following exception handler class

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlingAdvice {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExceptionHandlingAdvice.class);

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.REQUEST_TIMEOUT)
    @ExceptionHandler(AsyncRequestTimeoutException.class)
    public @ResponseBody ExceptionInfo handleAsyncRequestTimeoutException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Uncaught AsyncRequestTimeoutException", e);
        return new ExceptionInfo(request.getRequestURL().toString(), e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
```

The ExceptionInfo is just to capture the specific request URL and error message:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class ExceptionInfo {
    private final @NonNull String url;
    private final String exceptionMessage;
}
```

However, when the client aborts the request/reaches the request timeout, I would get the logs below and after some time the service application would stop consuming any further requests. I think the exception is being thrown when the response body is being written, but that happens behind the scenes and adding another handler method for the ClientAbortException doesn't seem to work. Any idea what's happening here and how to solve the issue?

```
@ExceptionHandler(ClientAbortException.class)
    public void handleClientAbortException(ClientAbortException e) {
        LOGGER.warn("A ClientAbortException has occurred", e.getMessage());
    }
```

Here's the complete stacktrace logs:

```
2022-09-21 15:48:24.323  WARN 1 --- [nio-8084-exec-5] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Failure in @ExceptionHandler 
my.package.controllers.ExceptionHandlingAdvice#handleAsyncRequestTimeoutException(HttpServletRequest, Exception)

org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: The current thread was interrupted
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:310) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:273) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:118) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.flush(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:523) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.flush(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:523) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.flush(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:523) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at java.base/java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:153) ~[na:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.flush(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1178) ~[jackson-core-2.11.4.jar!/:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1008) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar!/:2.11.4]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:454) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:290) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:124) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:428) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:75) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:141) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:80) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1320) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1131) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1077) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:106) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:87) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.4.5.jar!/:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:710) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:631) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:599) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl$AsyncRunnable.run(AsyncContextImpl.java:586) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.doInternalDispatch(AsyncContextImpl.java:354) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.asyncDispatch(CoyoteAdapter.java:249) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.dispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:241) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:59) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The current thread was interrupted
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.checkInterruptStatus(NioChannel.java:236) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:134) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:118) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:151) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:766) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flushBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:719) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flush(SocketWrapperBase.java:709) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.flush(Http11OutputBuffer.java:572) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.flush(IdentityOutputFilter.java:117) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.flush(Http11OutputBuffer.java:220) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.flush(Http11Processor.java:1196) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.action(AbstractProcessor.java:402) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:209) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:306) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:273) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:118) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.flush(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:523) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.flush(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:523) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar!/:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler$StreamingResponseBodyTask.call(StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler.java:112) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler$StreamingResponseBodyTask.call(StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler.java:98) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager.lambda$startCallableProcessing$4(WebAsyncManager.java:337) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the service doesn't actually stop consuming requests. The succeeding requests were just taking forever in one method being called in the controller. It also seems that the service is not able to do the request because there is no available connection in the PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager. It looked like the requests is not being processed but it's actually waiting indefinitely to make the request.

Setting the `logging.level.org.apache.http=DEBUG` in the `application.properties` helped me debug what's happening. It seems that the HTTP client object built from HttpClients.custom() doesn't have a default timeout https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-timeout#timeout-and-dns-round-robin---something-to-be-aware-of